# How to search in the favorite questions in AskUbuntu account?

Tags: discussion, feature-request, bookmarks, search

I m starting to have lot of favorite questions in my AskUbuntu account.
So it takes me some time to search and find a Question in my favorites.

- knowing that these questions have tags (like ATI, Wine, USB, UNITY, ...),
  is there a way to sort my favorite questions ?
- or is there a way to perform a query search in AskUbuntu specifying that I want to search only in my favorite questions?
  Something like this would be perfect:
  [image]

Comment: Related feature request in [metase]: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3683/search-in-list-of-favorited-questions

Answer (score 11, accepted):

This has been made possible after the [new elasticsearch engine.](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/160100/a-new-search-engine-for-stack-exchange)

To use it, go to https://askubuntu.com/search and use parameter `infavorites:mine` to limit to your favorite questions.

Comment: awesome - I love Ubuntu and AskUbuntu

Comment: suggest edit: infavorites:mine [unity] will show a list of just the questions with unity tag that are in your favorites.

Comment: suggest edit: infavorites:mine [unity] launcher; would give an even narrower search result.  Do not mean to appear condescending just found this good question and good answer.  And happenend to be looking in FAQ at same time at using tags as search tool.